# How to center an Anchor tag element both vertically and horizontally without any div?

Tags: html, css

So how to vertically and horizontally center an anchor tag link? No div or any parent elements used. i just want to center it as in the following image. 
[This is how i want it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N21G6.jpg)

And this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
background:#000;
}
.link{
font-size:40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center><a class="link" href="#">BornExplorer</a></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are more likely going to get a response, and helpful information, if you include your code that is not working, or approaches that you have attempted but have failed.

Comment: @AeroBuffalo i'm sorry. Now it is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going for a full page setup with a a single link you could setup the centering using `line-height:100vh` which means that the line height is 100% of the page height.

```css
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;}
body{
  background:#000;
  line-height:100vh;
}
.link{
  font-size:40px;
  line-height:1;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<center><a class="link" href="#">BornExplorer</a></center>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the width and height of the anchor tag box are fixed, it's pretty trivial. Assuming you want to position the tag relative to the viewport:

```css
html { background: black; color: white; }
.centered {
  /* size */
  width: 10em;
  height: 1em;
  
  /* positioning */
  margin-left: -5em; /* -(width/2) */
  margin-top: -0.5em; /* -(height/2) */
  position: fixed;    /* relative to viewport */
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  
  /* just aesthetic styling */
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

```html
<a class="centered" href="#">Centered</a>
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot for the help. :)